# Why is my UITableView reloading all of its section headers?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uitableview

I work on an app for managing user tasks. The app lists the tasks in a `UITableView`. Tasks for one day are grouped in one section. The section header shows the date and the number of tasks on that day:

***2014/05/03 - (42 tasks)***

A `NSFetchedResultsController` monitors the entity '*Tasks*'. When the user inserts a new task, he is asked for some details like a date, a time, a description and so on. The FRC recognizes the insertion or changes to attributes and calls the delegate methods:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{   
    switch(type)
    {         
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:            
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:            
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                               arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                               arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type)
    {                
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

**I have two problems with that:**

1. Performance problem: The `UITableView` seems to reload the whole section data after one pair of `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates`. It asks the data source again for the number of sections, the section titles and the number of rows in each section. (However, it does not ask again for all the cells, only if they have changed.) Because my section header shows the string mentioned above with the day and the number of tasks, this is a performance problem, because the title is generated by a combination of a `NSDateFormatter` and a Core Data count query.
2. Understanding problem: After a pair of `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` the `UITableView` asks for the section data always twice! That means that it asks twice in a row for how many sections there are, twice for each section's title, but only once for the number of rows in each section:

   1 pair of beginUpdates/endUpdates triggers:

   2x numberOfSectionsInTableView

   2x tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:

   1x tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

Comment: Why do you perform a query to count tasks rather than using `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: I've left out some filtering details that I do (for simplicity).

Comment: Do your calculations on a background queue and cache the result until the FRC changes.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, it is accurate that, after manipulating the table within beginUpdates and endUpdates, the UITableView will call numberOfRowsInSection: and titleForHeaderInSection: for every single section in the table.

For a table with a large number of sections and not many rows per section, this removes much of the advantage of removing/inserting rows instead of just calling reloadData. As far as I can tell, there is no way to avoid all of these delegate calls, other than to implement your own custom tableview.

That said, you can improve performance by removing the implementation of titleForHeaderInSection:. That same functionality can be implemented in the delegate's viewForHeaderInSection:, which only gets called for sections displayed on the the screen. That can reduce thousands of calls of titleForHeaderInSection to a handful of calls to viewForHeaderInSection. Combined with a strategy of fast pre-caching of the number of rows in each section, you can get reasonable performance, even for a table with 10,000 sections or more.